# Heap allocation source code in in jdk(G1GC)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, new-operator, heap-memory

I want to understand how java allocates objects in heap. I want to know which parts of the JDK code are triggered when the "**new**" keyword is used.
How can I define a function that a user can call from the java code and that would implement functionality in JDK source code?
I am aware of the fact that jdk14 uses G1GC as a default garbage collector and G1GC code is present in jdk14/src/hotspot/share/GC/G1 folder but I am unable to follow G1Allocator allocates memory to the user threads(if it does).

Comment: The actual allocation of memory on the heap occurs in the JVM, not in JDK code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there some internal allocator like malloc. Also can you please give reference to code where internal pointers are handled.
Ps: I am just getting started with the source code and have a little idea about how the things are managed internally.

Comment: Questions that boil down to "I need a link" are considered off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any known implementation will use `TLAB` (thread local allocation buffer) by default when allocating memory. Without it - the allocation would be much more slower. Though I have not dived into the code too much about this subject, you can start from [here, for example](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/d847a98a32cf/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/collectedHeap.hpp#l141).

There is a very good comment in the source code about what happens when a `new` is requested [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/d847a98a32cf/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/memAllocator.hpp#l64). Basically if `TLAB` can be used (an Object is not bigger than that for example), it will be; otherwise raw `malloc` for every `new` will be done.

Regarding `G1` here are the mains points of what it does. [A general explanation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/d847a98a32cf/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1CollectedHeap.hpp#l421) is again in the comments, with a phrase :

> All non-TLAB allocation requests should go to mem_allocate()

What `mem_allocate` does can be started from [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/d847a98a32cf/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1CollectedHeap.cpp#l389).